# How to hook the event or the changing of the windows in a WPF application?

Tags: c#

everyone, hope you well.
Here is the requirement: I have a C# WPF application, and I would like to track the events in this app.

Not a native speaker, forgive.
Thank you.

I found a mouse hook on 'https://github.com/justcoding121/Windows-User-Action-Hook', but it can hook the global events rather the events in the app.

This hook cannot hook the events in the WPF application.

Comment: There is no universal "hook wpf events" kind of hook, only the kind of events that the OS knows about.  Beyond keyboard and mouse hooks, the UI automation events tend to be interesting.  Be sure to not ask about the solution you had in mind, always describe the exact problem you try to solve.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to be aware of before we can get to the answer itself:

1) In WPF, everything except the window itself is artificial -- all UI elements are drawn via DirectX and not the operating system (which is why, for example, in WPF you can put a button into another button but in Windows Forms you can't). So there isn't a way for the operating system to somehow know about mouse events within the app.

2) Almost all events in WPF are routed -- that means, when a control fires an event, it can actually be handled in multiple places, typically on that control first and then up the tree to and including the window. Controls up (or down) the tree will fire this event even if it is not declared on them (like Click is not declared on a Window, but a window can still indirectly respond to clicks within itself).

That out of the way, you can use events either normally (for example, this.MouseMove += MyHandler; in the window constructor or <Window MouseDown="DownHandler" ...> in XAML) or through the routed events syntax (this.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, MyHandler); in C# or <Window Button.Click="ClickHandler" ...> in XAML). The latter is usually needed only when you handle an event that is not declared on the element (like Click on a Window).